# Play Framework 2.4.x custom deploy script

Tags: batch-file, typesafe-activator, playframework-2.4

I want to build my app with custom run script.
After 'activator stage' I get built app, with default run script.

So I need to replace default script with my own.

I need batch file like this:

```
@echo off
set "name=projectName"

activator clean stage || pause 1

del ".\target\universal\stage\bin\%name%.bat"

exit
```

But after calling 'activator clean stage' script automatically close, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is it not deleting projectName.bat, or are you expecting it to pause? Because that code won't pause unless activator fails.

Comment: This script doesnt reach this line: 'del ".\target\universal\stage\bin\%name%.bat"'.

I just want to delete file when 'stage' complete, but script automatically close after completion 'stage'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows then bat:

```
@echo off
activator clean stage
copy custom.bat c:\target\universal\stage\bin\myproject.bat
```

Where custom.bat is your bat that will be used for start the project.
But better look at custom configuration of your project 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionConfiguration